# Giving id to jQuery Tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have something like

```
<li><a href="SearchQC.do?mode=view">Add to QC List</a></li>
```

in my view.

jQuery automatically creates a div and assigns it the id ui-tabs-1 while running. How do I change that?

**EDIT**

I don't need to actually change it. If that id remains constant then no probs. But at a later stage if I add another tab before that then that id will be assigned to other one.

Comment: Why do you want to change it?

Comment: What do you want as ID? There is no ID specify in your code.

Comment: @MateiMihai i need the id to reload the tab content(div content dynamically). also couple of styling required for that.

Comment: I see no ID.  Please create a jfiddle

Comment: We cannot see any id at this level.. The ids are set automatically by the tabs plugin after the dom is loaded

Comment: @WernerVesterås id is created on running that. u can check source. u get a separate id for each tab which acts like a div.

Comment: @MateiMihai yup. exactly thats what i want. "ids are set automatically by the tabs plugin after the dom is loaded". Now i need to set that myself before execution.

Comment: @Bouillou "ids are set automatically by the tabs plugin after the dom is loaded" is there an option to preset id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guess you probably don't need it anymore... i am answering to this to help others that may face the same situation as you and i shared. I needed the same and with some research i was able to came up with this function...

```
$(window).load
        (function () {

            var abasRenomear = $('a[href^="#ui-tabs-"]');
            var abaRenomear = [];
            var divAba;

            for (var i = 0; i < abasRenomear.length; i++) {
                abaRenomear = abasRenomear[i];
                divAba = document.getElementById(abaRenomear.hash.substr(1, abaRenomear.hash.length - 1));                    
                divAba.setAttribute("id", abaRenomear.innerHTML);
                abaRenomear.setAttribute("href", "#" + abaRenomear.innerHTML);
            }
        }
    );
```

This way your divs' ids will be replaced, also the href attribute of your a tag to match it. They ll all get the tab's title (fixed id). I'm new to Jquery and JavaScript, so this solution may not be the best one, but seems to solve your request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$('#tabs li').each(function(){
    var new_id = '';
    switch($(this).attr('id')) {
        case 'ui-tabs-1':
            new_id = 'my_first_new_id';
        break;
        case 'ui-tabs-2':
            new_id = 'my_second_new_id';
        break;
    }

    $(this).attr('id',new_id);
});
```

Comment: what if i later add a new tab. then the new id will refer to something else.